# How can I wipe and trim my Intel 320 SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have an Intel 320 SSD and want to wipe all contents, and trim the whole drive.

The Intel SSD Toolbox for Windows can do this, but does not allow me, saying that the drive is "locked" without providing me any more information, even when the filesystems on the drive are not mounted.

What other ways are there, on Windows or Linux, to wipe and trim my SSD?

Comment: Can you read/write any data to the drive? Have you followed the steps in this forum (specifically the 3rd post in the list): http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-resurrect-an-intel-ssd-locked-by-the-intel-ssd-toolbox.583269/

Comment: I think that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is to use f.ex. hdparm on a Linux system to un-freeze and/or set a drive password, which will then allow you to issue an ATA Secure Erase command to wipe and trim the whole drive:

https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase